# Nginx looking for html5 appcache file in wrong directory

Tags: nginx, html5-appcache

My manifest.appcache file is located at http://example.com/manifest.appcache however NGINX is looking for this file at `/usr/share/nginx/html/manifest.appcache`

I even added the following in my example.conf file:

```
 location /manifest.appcache {
   try_files $uri  /home/sushi/www/example/manifest.appcache;
 }
```

And my root is set as

```
root /home/sushi/www/example/;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you share the whole nginx config? it's probably that your request is matching the default server not the virtual server that you think it's matching.

Comment: Thanks. Here you go: https://gist.github.com/sushimashi/6653621

Comment: actually i wanted the ones inside `sites-enabled`, or to be exact, the file which contains that `location` block and the `try_files`

Comment: Oh here is that one: https://gist.github.com/sushimashi/6654263

Comment: ok a random idea came up my mind, did you restart the nginx server after creating the virutal server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nginx config looks fine if the `server_name` is exactly what you are using then I don't know exactly what's wrong, but let me tidy up your config, might help

For redirection I prefer to use a separate server to do the redirection instead of using an if condition

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 example.com$request_uri;
}
```

No need to re-declare the root and the index. specifying them once in the server block level is enough.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /home/sushi/www/example/;
    access_log /home/sushi/www/example/logs/access.log;
    error_log /home/sushi/www/example/logs/error.log;
    index index.html index.htm;
    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Since your `manifest.appcache` is exactly where `$uri` would look then you don't need to explicitly mention it, The issue is that nginx won't match the server block.

Another random idea is that maybe nginx doesn't know that the server exists, cause you didn't restart nginx after creating a server.. did you try that ?

***EDIT***: The block inside the `nginx.conf` should be moved here inside the `example.conf` file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /home/sushi/www/example/;
    access_log /home/sushi/www/example/logs/access.log;
    error_log /home/sushi/www/example/logs/error.log;
    index index.html index.htm;
    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
        expires -1;
        access_log logs/static.log;
    }
}
```

Comment: inside `sites-enabled` you have a file called `default` right ? can you paste the `listen` and `server_name` lines please, does it have the same server name as this one ?

Comment: Here you go: https://gist.github.com/sushimashi/6657469 Also just want to say thanks again for your help so far.

Comment: If it helps, I also removed the default file from sites-enabled, restarted server and the problem persists.

Comment: ok i want to make sure of something, what's your nginx version ? is it 1.2.6? or 1.1.9?

Comment: nginx version: nginx/1.4.1

Comment: ok so here's a thing you need to check, all nginx versions above 1.2 will not restart if the configuration is not ok, try `sudo nginx -t`

Comment: Alright, so nginx was showing couple of errors, first because of line 9 on https://gist.github.com/sushimashi/6653621 and then because of all the content in mime.types. I removed every single entry from  mime.types which means the appcache file is no longer 404. Success. However since now I removed mime-types for appcache file they are still being served with Content-Type: application/octet-stream.

Comment: the issue is probably that the location block is outside the server block and even http block, you should move this block to the settings file inside `sites-enabled`, and return the mime.types file as it was, http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location check the context, should be inside either a server block or another location block